solana jitotip instruction
whenever I use a systemprogram.trnasfer instruction for a jitotip public address to speed up block validation on SOLANA I get a timeout instead of having a faster confirmation.
I have no clue why it does that, and whenever I remove the instruction it seems to work perfectly fine.
p.s -> I do add a custom CUs instruction as the first instruction of the transaction.
